# Problem while looping variables for Scipy Optimization (SLSQP, COBYLA)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I have a constrained optimization problem where I am trying to minimize an objective function of 100+ variables which is of the form

Min F(x) = f(x1) + f(x2) + ... + f(xn)

Subject to functional constraint

(g(x1) + g(x2) + ... + g(xn))/(f(x1) + f(x2) + ... + f(xn)) - constant >= 0

I also have individual bounds for each variable x1, x2, x3...xn
a <= x1 <= b
c <= x2 <= d
...

For this, I wrote a python script, using the `scipy.optimize.minimize` implementation with constraints and bounds, but I am unable to fulfill my bounds and constraints in the solutions. These are all cases where optimization could converge to a solution (message: success)

Here is a sample of my code:

`df` is my pandas dataset
`B(x)` is LogNorm transform based on x and other constants
Values `U, c, lb, ub` are pre-calculated constant dictionaries for each index in df

```
import scipy

df  = pd.DataFrame(..)

k = set(df.index.values)   ## list of indexes to iterate on 

val = 0.25                 ## Arbitrary

def obj(x):
    fn =  0
    for n,i in enumerate(k):
        x0 = x[n]
        fn1 = (U[i]) * B(x0) * (x0)                                                   
        fn += fn1
    return fn

def cons(x):
    cn = 1
    c1 = 0
    c2 = 0
    for n,i in enumerate(k):
        x0 = x[n]
        c1 += (U[i]) * (B(x0) * (x0 - c[i])                                     
        c2 += (U[i]) * (B(x0) * (x0)
    cn = c1/(c2)
    
    return cn - val

const = [{'type':'ineq', 'fun':cons}]

bnds = tuple((lb[i], ub[i]) for i in k)    ## Lower, Upper for each element ((lb1, ub1), (lb2, ub2)...)
x_init = [lb[i] for i in k]                  ## for eg. starting from lower bound


## Solution
sol = scipy.optimize.minimize(obj, x_init, method = 'COBYLA', bounds = bnds, constraints = const)
```

I have more pointed questions if that helps:

1. Is there a way to construct the same equation concisely/ without the use of loops (given the number of variables could depend on input data and I have no control over it)?
2. Is there any noticeable issue in my application of **bounds**? I can't seem to get the final values of all variables follow individual bounds.
3. Similarly, is there a visible flaw in the construction on constraint equation? My results often  DO NOT follow the constraints is repeated runs with different inputs.

Any help with either of the questions can help me progress further at work.
I have also looked into a **Lagrangian** solution of the same but so far I am unable to solve it for undefined number of (n) variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Updated in the text! Thanks for pointing. The constraint should be inequality based.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide a full minimal **working** example by providing all your data and functions, i.e. `df, U, c, lb, ub, B` such that we can copy-paste your code snippet and run it?

Comment: `Similarly, is there a visible flaw in the construction on constraint equation?` The docs say that COBYLA doesn't support the bounds parameter. Other than that, I would echo what joni said. Hard to give advice without being able to run it myself.